# Beamer: changing background color leaves white lines above and below title

Tags: beamer, color

It must be simple but I don't find the last missing bit. I'm making a beamer presentation where I want single slides with a different background color.

However, when I set the background color using `\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=red}` or `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=red}`, there are still two white horizontal lines surrounding the frame title and I cannot find out how to change the color of those or how to remove them.

Even using `[plain]` for the frame does not get rid of those.

Below is a working example.

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{color}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\useoutertheme{smoothbars}
\useoutertheme{infolines} % header and footer
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{} % no header line
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{slide 1}
  first
 \end{frame}
{
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=yellow!20}
 \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{slide 2}
  second
 \end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need outerthemes for header and footer and color package. Comment those out and it should work fine.

Comment: As @percusse said, the line to comment is (if I understood right) `\useoutertheme{smoothbars}`, try to complile because for me it worked well.

Comment: Man, some relict from some early template I copied. Shame on me. Thanks so much for the help, deleting \useoutertheme{smoothbars} exactly solved my problem.

Comment: @AndreaL. Can you write up an answer?

Comment: @percusse Yes, sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the adding of `\useoutertheme{smoothbars}` tends to be the main reason of the problem, so commenting the lines gives for the code:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
%\usepackage{color} beamer loads xcolor anyway
\usecolortheme{rose}
\useoutertheme{infolines} % header and footer
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{} % no header line
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{slide 1}
  first
 \end{frame}
{
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=yellow!20}
 \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{slide 2}
  second
 \end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

A working example with the output:

> [image]
>
> [image]

That basically solves the issue.